# What are known space avionics open hardware projects?

Tags: avionics

We have seen many community projects towards open hardware.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_hardware_projects

What is state of the art for space avionics?

Comment: Possibly related; https://libre.space/ and http://librecube.net/

Comment: It should be noted that national and international arms trade regulations (due to the overlap between civil space and military rocket/missile/guidance applications) can make open source space hardware legally problematic.